# Listview with no items in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show empty view when ListView is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/how-to-show-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty)

I have one listview on one activity. the listview binds from db. so if no result from db then how can i show "No items" inplace of listview in android.I have done like following but it shows Empty_list on upper side , i want it on same place of listview.

```
public TextView emptyshow;
lstview.setAdapter(adapter);
emptyshow=(TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
lstview.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
```

Comment: set its Visibility to GONE. And you can show Toast or TextView to show the message about Blanck DB.

Answer (score 3):

From the  doc

> Optionally, your custom view can contain another view object of any
>   type to display when the list view is empty. This "empty list"
>   notifier must have an id "android:id/empty". Note that when an empty
>   view is present, the list view will be hidden when there is no data to
>   display.

So, inside your layout declare an optional view with id:

```
android:id/empty
```

and change its visibility accordingly: