# Android - dismiss progress bar automatically

Tags: android, progress-bar

when the app is launched, I inflate a progress bar from **main.xml** file which is shown until the list is empty. Once the list is populated with data which is coming from URL, i should dismiss this progress bar.
How can i do this without using progress dialog?

my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_places"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/empty_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/how-to-show-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty

Comment: thanks for the link. it was the right one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like:

```
ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.empty_progress_bar);
bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This solution works. Alternative is listview.setEmptyView(prog_bar);

Answer (score 3):

If you will use list fragment then progress bar is automatically handled. once data is populated it will automatically dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
globalProgressDialog.dismissProgressDialog();
```