# How to delete progressBar in android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I already know  `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)` can hide the progress bar.

But is it same as the `ProgressDialog.dismiss()`?

I can only use progressBar due to [AsyncTask block Unity(UI) thread issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573639/asynctask-block-unityui-thread-issue).

What I want to achieve is to delete it permanently not just hide it for some time.

Comment: Delete it permanently? Why? Just set the visibility.

Comment: ProgressBar and ProgressDialog are two different things.  The first is a view and the second is a Dialog that contains a view.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Because after it show the progress for some time, it is not needed any more.

Comment: first dismiss it by using .dismiss() then set it to null if u wana release it

Comment: when you do View.GONE, the view is actually removed from the view heirarchy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - dismiss progress bar automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854457/android-dismiss-progress-bar-automatically)

Comment: @Bhargav Yes.But when I set the visibility to true, it will be added again. But I am sure the view will not be used anymore.  Is there any way to delete it permanent?

Comment: @AlexWei You don't gain anything by deleting it. As long as you are in the same layout then the `View` is just going to be there.

Comment: when you do View.GONE the view IS DELETED from the view hierarchy, only the view object is cached only if you hold a reference to the object in your class, if just assign that ref to null, then its effectively deleting the view, but the xml file will stil contain whatever you typed and since you gave this view an ID, there will be an ID reference to it in the R class, but if you were to create the ProgressBar programatically when you need it, then by removing reference to the progress bar you would be effectively deleting it

Comment: @Bhargav Thanks. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: @AlexWei oops View.GONE apparently doesn't remove it from view hierarchy what you can do to remove it is do `((ViewGroup)mProgressBar.getParent().removeView(mProgressBar))` which would actually remove the view from its parent, make sure the parent is castable to `ViewGroup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do View.GONE the view IS DELETED from the view hierarchy, only the view object is cached only if you hold a reference to the object in your class, if just assign that ref to null, then its effectively deleting the view, but the xml file will stil contain whatever you typed and since you gave this view an ID, there will be an ID reference to it in the R class, but if you were to create the ProgressBar programatically when you need it, then by removing reference to the progress bar you would be effectively deleting it

**EDIT**

oops View.GONE apparently doesn't remove it from view hierarchy what you can do to remove it is do

`((ViewGroup)mProgressBar.getParent()).removeView(mProgressBar)`

which would actually remove the view from its parent, make sure the parent is castable to `ViewGroup`

Comment: So only call View.Gone doesn't delete itself from the view hierarchy. And I also need to call removeView. Am I correct?

Comment: @AlexWei yes removingView will definitely delete it, setting View.GONE is upto you, but by just doing removeView the view will be removed, which means you dont have to set visibility separately

Answer (score 0):

`ProgressDialog` is obviously a dialog so you can dismiss it, but `ProgressBar` is a view, so it's ok to just hide it using visibility.

Comment: Yes. But if I am pretty sure that I won't need the progressBar anymore, Is there any way to delete it permanent?

Comment: There is no problem if it stays in gone so you don't have to worry about it.