# Filter Null then Return Message in List or TextView Vs Returning Nothing

Tags: android, filtering

I have a simple filter on an xml file in my android application:

```
public void runFilter() {

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, R.id.productInfo, xmlr());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {    
               //like to return a message or line of text "No Results"
               adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        // clear edittext contents for next scan
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);
                et.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
```

I would like to have the listview show a message "NO ITEMS FOUND" or something like that...

I've tried an if else in the onTextChanged, but didn't get results...

```
if(s.toString().equals(null)){
   //show message
}else{
   //show results
}
```

What am I missing?

Edit:::

If I add a Toast for example, to the afterTextChanged, I'll get something in a toast... I guess that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question answered it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3771631/350421

Just put this:

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="No Results" />
```

...in your XML layout.

Mine turned out like this:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Results... Scan next item." //use @string here... 
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```