# MvvmCross MvxListView EmptyView is null and not displaying even when list is empty

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I cannot access MvxListView's EmptyView property. Any idea what am I missing here?

My layout code:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listelement" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/empty">
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/emptyTextView"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And when I try to access EmptyView, it's null. Here is what I tried:

```
var list = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
list.EmptyView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.emptyTextView); //EmptyView is null here
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/6135729/373321 help? - if it does, then please upvote it :)

Comment: Thank you, it definetly helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your ***TextView*** to ***EmptyView***.

```
this.listView.EmptyView = (Android.Widget.TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.emptyTextView);
```