# how to display Not Listview found item in android

Tags: android

```
   public static void loadPopupData(Context context, final ListView listView) {
        final DataBaseManager dbManager1 = new DataBaseManager(context);
        final ArrayList<Notify> notifies = dbManager1.getNotificationList(15);

        Notifcationadapter adapter = new Notifcationadapter(context, notifies);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    }
```

This method is use to Print data In listview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#00000000" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_tringle"
            android:layout_width="40px"
            android:layout_height="21px"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/notficationarrow_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:background="@anim/notifcationitembroder" >
    </ListView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/emptyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listView1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="No items in list" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_top"
        android:background="@drawable/bgnotifcationlayoutback"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Notification"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is Xml File where am Printing Listview .

i want when there is no item in Listview then it should display Not found Listview  am try to do But unable to display it please suggest me how to display Not found item if there is not item in list view .

Comment: Just check if your `arraylist.length()==0` then display what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty views for listview

[Setting emptyview to Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your xml

```
 <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="No Results" />
```

and this code in your activity contains list

```
public static void loadPopupData(Context context, final ListView listView) {
        final DataBaseManager dbManager1 = new DataBaseManager(context);
        final ArrayList<Notify> notifies = dbManager1.getNotificationList(15);

        Notifcationadapter adapter = new Notifcationadapter(context, notifies);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
    }
```

Comment: NO its not working plz check my code then Edit my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. If this is not your solution in else add another view to display there is no any records to display

```
public String[] getSociety() {
    int pos = 0;
    MFDbBHelper mDbHelper = new MFDbBHelper(this);
    List<Society> society = mDbHelper.getAllSociety();
    String[] values = null;
    if (society.size() > 0) {

        values = new String[society.size()];
        for (Society socty : society) {

            values[pos] = socty.get_society_name();

            // Writing Society to log
            String log = "Id: " + socty.get_society_id() + " ,Name: "
                    + socty.get_society_name();
            Log.d("Insert: ", log);

            pos++;
        }
    } else {

        values = new String[0];
        values[0] = "No records found!";
    }
    return values;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a text view which shows "No Results" in your popup's xml file and give it a id.

something like this

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/emptyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listView1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="No items in list" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

And in code part set the textview as emptyview of your listview.

```
 public static void loadPopupData(Context context, final ListView listView) {
        final DataBaseManager dbManager1 = new DataBaseManager(context);
        final ArrayList<Notify> notifies = dbManager1.getNotificationList(15);

        Notifcationadapter adapter = new Notifcationadapter(context, notifies);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView));
    }
```

Comment: But after getting data in Listview item tha textview  android:text="No items in list" not disappearing

Comment: then keep the textview invisible by default. Updated my answer.

Comment: after changer ur code my Listview is looking like this when i add ur code http://snag.gy/Zc7jK.jpg

Comment: in this case if Listview will Empty then also it will not show ?

Comment: it should work,i checked it in my app just now. Are you sure you are not doing anything else?. Can you update your question with updated layout and code?

Comment: I have checked with your code also, it is working perfectly fine for me. You might be doing something else which is causing the problem.