# ListFragment with custom layout doesn't populate empty list notifier

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

I have created a custom layout for ListFragment, using ArrayAdapter, but when the array is empty, no empty message is displayed. I get no errors on the console. My min SDK version is 15, there should be no need to use support libraries.

**headline_list.xml** (i.e. my custom layout file)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@id/android:list" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

**HeadlineFragment.java**

```
public class HeadlineFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.headline_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<String> headlines = ...;          // populate headlines list

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.headline_list, R.id.my_text, headlines));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had simply forgot to set the text!

After setting it, my TextView is displayed correctly:

```
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/empty_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

with string resource in strings.xml file:

```
<string name="empty_text">There are no data</string>
```

Unfortunately, the TextView is also displayed in each row of the list, but this is another question.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting suggestions here, you should do the tries..  Anyway this layout is working perfectly for me:

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
        }

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmet"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No Results" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be related to the linear layout and the fact you didn't specified weight attribute to each of the items, so one may overlay another. Check your layout params and this:
[Showing empty view when ListView is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty)

Comment: Have you tried yourself? You have simply linked someone else's answer, and that answer didn't work in my case.