# ListView adds empty view to root/parent instead of self?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to add a custom empty view to a `ListView` as shown in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty).  But the `ListView` seems to add the empty view to its parent, or maybe to the root `ViewGroup`, rather than to itself.  Am I doing something wrong here?

I created a small layout file that demonstrates the problem.  Notice how the empty view is placed in the top left corner of the activity, completely outside the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Some text above the ListView" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ListView empty text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong here?" -- well, you probably want to center that `TextView`. That is governed by the layout rules that you apply, and right now, you have it set to be in the upper-left-hand corner.

Comment: @CommonsWare Agreed.  But the immediate problem is which view it's in the upper-left-hand corner of.

Comment: Well, it has to be somewhere. It can't be a child of `ListView`. If you don't like where it is, move it elsewhere. You have not really explained what the problem is.

Comment: @CommonsWare Aren't the list items children of the `ListView`?  If not, then the problem is my assumption that they are and that the empty view should be also.  If that's wrong, then what's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aren't the list items children of the ListView?

Yes, when the `ListView` creates them via the associated `ListAdapter`.

The empty view is not a list item. It is not a child of the `ListView`. It is simply another view. `AdapterView` toggles the visibility of itself and the empty view, depending upon whether or not the `AdapterView` is empty. If the `AdapterView` is empty, its own visibility is set to `GONE` and the empty view is set to `VISIBLE`. If the `AdapterView` is not empty, its own visibility is set to `VISIBLE` and that of the empty view is set to `GONE`. See `updateEmptyStatus()` in [the source code for `AdapterView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java).

Given the visibility toggle effect, the typical approach is to have the empty view roughly occupy the same space as does the `ListView`. However, that's not a requirement.