# Create default message on empty fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have two fragments in my app which both contains a listview. The first fragment is meant to hold user entries(text based notes), user has an option of setting reminders to these notes so they can be notified. This is where the second fragment comes in. By swipping right, user can see a list of their notes with reminder set for them in a listview. Question is when there are no set reminders (meaning, nothing to show in the reminder fragment) I want to be able to show a default message at the centre of the screen instead of having a blank page. Unfortunately, I can't add image to this post as I'm new to stackoverflow and don't have enough reputation yet. Please see this link for a description of what I intend to implement.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilu2aixe99sap9f/Screenshot_2015-06-12-19-54-06.png?dl=0

EDIT: I'm using a custom adapter for the listview which is being populated with information from database.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Honestly speaking, I have't tried anything yet. Done some search online and haven't come across anything related... and I honestly don't know what to do for a start. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to add an empty view to your list view, like this: 
[Showing empty view when ListView is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped.. Just needed someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks once again.