# Showing empty view when ViewGroup is empty

Tags: java, android, viewgroup

Similar to [Showing empty view when ListView is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty), but I want to display text in my ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc) when it has no children. I have tried setOnHierarchyChangeListener, but it causes a NPE. I believe it may be related to the fact that I'm animating layout changes- I've had a bug related to that before, but I was wondering if there's a better way. Here's my current code.

```
flowLayout.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    RelativeLayout textView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_no_widgets, flowLayout, false);

    @Override
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
        if (child != textView) {
            if (textView.getParent() == flowLayout) {
                flowLayout.removeView(textView);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {
        if (flowLayout.getChildCount() == 0) {
            flowLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so you want show some msg like No Record ??

Comment: @UttamPanchasara yes

Comment: then first check of your data from where ur getting if it is list then check if `list.size()` if list having data then display your data or else just Show Message in Textview

Comment: by default Textview will be invisible/gone only do visible when your view is empty or your data list or whatever is null

Comment: Ah thank you. That avoids adding/re-adding the view.

Comment: happy to help! so you get the idea right how to do ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I needed