# Change listview layout if empty

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-xml

I use an adapter to set the item layout and to populate a `ListView` from a JSON string. Sometimes this JSON is empty and there aren't any rows into the `ListView` and it's full blank.

In this case, I want to change the view and pass another layout showing "There aren't any rows here".

So this is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List list = new LinkedList();

        [...fill list...]

        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_layout, list, R.id.edCod, R.id.edDes);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Adapter> {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private int layout;
    private int textCod;
    private int textDes;

    public FruttaAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Adapter> objects, int textCod, int textDes) {
        super(context, layout, objects);

        this.layout = layout;
        this.textCod = textCod;
        this.textDes = textDes;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

Comment: We need a mod to mark this is an exact duplicate

Comment: Also to @Simone, there is no point to add "Android Studio:" to your questions or as a tag. One could have this same exact question without using Android Studio. The tag is specifically for questions *about* the IDE itself, not the processes of writing the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty

Answer (score 3):

You can use `listView.setEmptyView(yourEmptyView)`.

Comment: Please vote to close as a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Actually, You could use a [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) or [ListFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and use its `EmptyView` (any View which has the id android.R.id.empty)

Comment: Actually `android.R.id.empty`, with `@android:id/empty`, but that is discussed in the duplicate post

Comment: yep, voted close. But corrected it anyway.