# SetEmptyView is not displaying textView

Tags: android

I have added the emptyView value into the main.xml, but when the listview is empty it does not show anything. I am using a custom listview
But if I only call my textView like this

```
listView.setEmptyView(textEmpty);
```

it would work, but I wanted to use a layout to put multiple items

Can anyone help me with my problem? Thanks in advance!

My Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_cart"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context="com.example.gin.ordering.cart">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ></ListView>

<!-- empty view -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/emptyView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEmpty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YOUR CART IS EMPTY!"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCheckout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CHECKOUT"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_below="@id/listView"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

ListCartAdapter adapter = new ListCartAdapter(cart.this, orderid, orderName, 
orderSize, orderQuantity);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing empty view when ListView is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty)

Comment: @VikasTiwari Well sir I have tried this particular answer, the problem is that it does not work sir. That's why I posted this question so that some people could help. Do you have an idea with my problem sir?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran Well sir I have tried this particular answer, the problem is that it does not work sir. That's why I posted this question so that some people could help. Do you have an idea with my problem sir?

Comment: post your complete Main.xml

Comment: @AliAhsan Posted it sir :)

Comment: what's the parent layout for button    btnCheckout?

Comment: sorry for that sir I have added it already did not notice that.

Comment: @GionneLapuz what it is showing when adapter is empty? if possible can you add screenshot?

Comment: @GionneLapuz you xml and MainActivity.java code seems correct, there is no issue, pls check your adapter class and make sure you data is empty during initialization of adapter.

Comment: yes possible, can u check like this ((ViewGroup) listView.getParent()).addView(emptyView)

Comment: @Lingeshwaran well sir got it working, thanks again for all the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout        
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_cart"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context="com.example.gin.ordering.cart">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

></ListView>

<!-- empty view -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textEmpty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="YOUR CART IS EMPTY!"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

    </LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnCheckout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="CHECKOUT"
android:layout_gravity="right"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And In OnCreate of Main Activity before setting adapter to listView:

```
ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
view.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.textEmpty));
```

Let me know if that's help

Comment: Sir may I ask is it possible to use layout for an emptyview?

Comment: you are welcome. keep in mind empty view and listView should be in same layout

Comment: Yes sir thank you. Sir may I ask one more question, what if I wanted to display mutiple items when emptyview is shown, what could I do?

Comment: instead of textView?

Comment: yes sir like would it be possible if I create a linearlayout and then name it textEmpty and then make it the setemptyview so that when the listview is emppty it will show a textview and a button?

Comment: yes you can but make sure that that linearlayout is inside listView parent layout

Answer (score 0):

You mean ListView and ListItem (EmptyView) right?

You need -
ListView xml,
ListItem xml,
ListItem class,
ArrayAdaper class

Comment: Sir can you please explain what are you talking about?