# Android search filter show text view when no result

Tags: java, android

I have a list view and search view. When the search filter gives results that doesnt match any item
in list view, I need to show a textview as "Nothing present". How can I do that?

Here is my xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="60dp"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your code that do the filter?

Comment: Just add a TextView after SwipeRefreshLayout and make it invisible by default. If there are no results then make it visible and the listview invisible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing empty view when ListView is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, on your list view adapter, when the array that you are using is empty, on your getItemCount, you return 1, and when you return the view, if the array is empty you return a view with the "Nothing present".